# Why won't my Div elements stay in line?

Tags: html, css, inline

I've gone through the forum and seemed to have tried all the suggestions related to div layouts. I'm trying to get two rows of elements as follows:
Row 1 - Number > Image > Text.
Row 2 - (Blank Space to move second row right by the same amount of pixels as the above image) > Number > Image > Text.

This is my code that I've tried so far:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Londrina+Sketch);

body {
  background-color: #f3eedd;
  width: 750px;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Londrina Sketch', cursive;
  color: #c13e18;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #c13e18;
  margin: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 30px 30px 0px 30px;
}

h4 {
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
}

.choose {}

.number {
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
}

.choose-image {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.choose-text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  float: left;
}

.customise {} 

.empty-left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.customise-image {
  display: inline-block;
}

.customise-text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<h1>FROM BEGINNING TO END</h1>
<hr>
<h2>How many? What size? How old? When and why? How much? 
    If you’d like to learn more about group sizes, room dimensions, prices & age limits … this section must have your answer! However if you can’t find it, please don’t hesitate to drop us a line!</h2>
<hr>
<!-- choose -->
<div class="choose">
  <div class="number">
    <h4>1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="choose-image">
    <img src="http://www.challenge-the-box.com/wp-content/uploads/choose.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="choose-text">Choose text content goes here</div>
</div>​
<div class="customise">
  <div class="empty-left"></div>
  <div class="number">
    <h4>2</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="customise-image">
    <img src="http://www.challenge-the-box.com/wp-content/uploads/customise.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="customise-text">Customise text content goes here</div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: use float and width also.

Comment: Also change ( to { in number class.

Comment: Float no!!! Inline-block YES! It is no floating element, it is an inline block element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve with your code. I'll let you into a little secret of mine ;)

I call it a split, which I can split into multiple columns and rows.

here's my CSS

```
.clearfix:after{clear:both;content:'';visibility:hidden;display:block;}
/*because floats have to be cleared. I use a simple clarify method
  although this may cause problems in IE <8
*/
@media only screen and (min-width:600px){/*use this if you want the elements to only be in columns for desktop computers.*/
    .split .splitOb{float:left;padding:1%;}
    .splitOb.w1{width:8%;}
    .splitOb.w2{width:18%;}
    .splitOb.w3{width:28%;}
    .splitOb.w4{width:38%;}
    .splitOb.w5{width:48%;}
    .splitOb.w6{width:58%;}
    .splitOb.w7{width:68%;}
    .splitOb.w8{width:78%;}
    .splitOb.w9{width:88%;}
}
```

The to use this idea, just use this basic structure.

```
<div class="split clearfix">
    <div class="splitOb w5">
        this is on the left side
    </div>
    <div class="splitOb w5">
        this is the right side
    </div>
</div>
```

Bare in mind though that all splitOb or split objects must equal to 10. You can make different variations of this and even reverse the order of your rows.

little bit of maths to help :)

with the percentages, you want to equal 100%. As whatever the parent's width, a child element with `width:100%;` will equal 100% of the parent.

So lets say I use the above example, there are 2 `.splitOb.w5` so that's 48% x 2 = 96% now there's padding on each side of 1%. 1% x 4 = 4%. 4% + 96% = 100%. It's the same with all the other widths.

Also, try not to use a pixel width on the body. I say this as there are so many different ratios out there, ranging from say 320px x 400px to 1440px x 900px and larger!!!

using a viewport with help you get the device's width

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

This will mean if you did this:

```
body,html{width:100%;margin:0px;padding:0px;}
```

Both the body and html will be 100% of the device's or browser's width.

Comment: Cheers for this. Even though you wrote a great in depth explanation I'm a having a hard time understanding this concept.

Comment: @Marc that's alright :) Basically, everything is on percentages. Everything needs to be 100%. What bit didn't you get? I'll try explaining it differently :)

Comment: @Marc just put this together for you :) Hope it helps to understand how the method works http://jsfiddle.net/rw1gv3ks/2/

Comment: Thank you so much!! That jsfiddle makes so much sense! I've now messed around using your idea and other than a few bits of content that needs to be created finished that page. Thanks!!! [have a look here](http://www.challenge-the-box.com/what-is-it) and click on 'From Beginning To End'.

Comment: @Marc Pretty neat and simple idea isn't it :) all I ask is that you accept my answer and keep it a secret :p shhhh

Answer (score 2):

u have a typo:

```
.number (
display: inline-block;
float: left;
}
```

change to:

```
.number {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    }
```

after it`s corrected it looks fine i think.

On your site, change this:

```
.customise {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.choose {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

to that:

```
.customise {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
 }

 .choose {
       float: left;
       width: 50%;
  }
```

Comment: Yes, and removing `float:left` works too, and works better, and it's not neccessary clearfixes, and is more correct.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that. I've changed the ( to a { and have removed 'float: left;', however my numbers div appears above the other two. [Example](http://www.challenge-the-box.com/what-is-it) then click on the middle circle labelled 'from beginning to end' to see what I mean.

Comment: Did you tried to make the box that you code is appearing in bigger? Or resize the sorted elements, to me it looks like it`s just don`t fit in the box, and it`s hooping the to other line, like any element will float: left would do.

Comment: @Marc it is produced by the `float:left` that you have in `.splitOb`. Remove it and put `display:inline-block; vertical-align:top` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Currently change add below style

    .choose {
        width: 50%; float: left;
        }​

        .customise {
            width: 50%;
            float: left;
        }​


 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <style>
      @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Londrina+Sketch);

      body {
      background-color: #f3eedd;
      width: 750px;
      overflow:scroll;
        overflow-x:hidden;
      }
      h1 {
        font-family: 'Londrina Sketch', cursive;
        color: #c13e18;
        font-size: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #c13e18;
        margin: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
    }

      h3 {
        font-size: 20px;
        margin: 30px 30px 0px 30px;
    }

    h4 {
    text-align: center;
    }

        p {
        font-size: 20px;
        margin: 0px 30px 0px 30px;

    }

    .choose {
    width: 50%; float: left;
    }​

    .number (
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;


    }

    .choose-image {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;

    }

    .choose-text {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;

    }

    .customise {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
    }​

    .empty-left {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;

    }

    .customise-image {
    display: inline-block;

    }

    .customise-text {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;

    }


    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>FROM BEGINNING TO END</h1>
    <hr>
    <h2>How many? What size? How old? When and why? How much? 
    If you’d like to learn more about group sizes, room dimensions, prices & age limits … this section must have your answer! However if you can’t find it, please don’t hesitate to drop us a line!</h2>
    <hr>
    <!-- choose -->
    <div class="choose">
    <div class="number"><h4>1</h4></div>
    <div class="choose-image">
    <img src="http://www.challenge-the-box.com/wp-content/uploads/choose.png" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="choose-text">Choose text content goes here</div>
    </div>​
    <div class="customise">
    <div class="empty-left"></div>
    <div class="number"><h4>2</h4></div>
    <div class="customise-image">
    <img src="http://www.challenge-the-box.com/wp-content/uploads/customise.png" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="customise-text">Customise text content goes here</div>
    </div>
    <!-- customise -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `display: table` or just make a table, unless your'e concerned about semantics. I'm not sure what the space is for here's a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/rLasau8f/1/)

I made another version without that space it looks a lot [better](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/g1sy1cpd/)